# transform integer value patterns in a column to a group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

DataFrame

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'occurance':[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],'value':[45, 3, 2, 12, 14, 32, 1, 1, 6, 4, 9, 32, 78, 96, 12, 6, 3]})
df
```

Expected output

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'occurance':[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],'value':[45, 3, 2, 12, 14, 32, 1, 1, 6, 4, 9, 32, 78, 96, 12, 6, 3],'group':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 100, 5, 5, 5, 5]})
df
```

I need to transform the dataframe into the output. I am after a wild card that will determine 1 is the start of a new group and a group consists of only 1 followed by n zeroes. If a group criteria is not met, then group it as 100.

I tried in the line of;

```
bs=df[df.occurance.eq(1).any(1)&df.occurance.shift(-1).eq(0).any(1)].squeeze()
bs
```

This even when broken down could only bool select start and nothing more.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask by compare `1` and next `1` in `mask`, then filter `occurance` for all values without them, create cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and last add `100` values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
m = df.occurance.eq(1) & df.occurance.shift(-1).eq(1)
df['group']  = df.loc[~m, 'occurance'].cumsum().reindex(df.index, fill_value=100)
print (df)
    occurance  value  group
0           1     45      1
1           0      3      1
2           0      2      1
3           0     12      1
4           1     14      2
5           0     32      2
6           0      1      2
7           0      1      2
8           0      6      2
9           0      4      2
10          1      9      3
11          0     32      3
12          1     78    100
13          1     96      4
14          0     12      4
15          0      6      4
16          0      3      4
```